# Set an error message in SharePoint desginer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

How to create an error pop up in Sharepoint desginer 2013?
Is there a way where, I can set a user message if a condition check fails in Sharepoint desginer 2013?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add error popup in a list form using SharePoint designer 2013, we can open the form page and find the "PlaceHolderMain", then add some JavaScript code in the below.
[image]

If you want to make the error popup works in all page, we can add the code into  in master page using SharePoint designer.

If I misunderstand your requirement, I suggest you provide more information for further research.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can explain me that what basically your code does as I do not have much understanding of code.

Comment: Basically, I am making a leave planner, where I want workflow to check the condition, and if the condition does not match then should display an error pop and not let user to make request.

Comment: For an example, if [availed+number of days]<=10, then let the workflow start approval process, else displays an error pop message.

Comment: Do you want to pop up error message in SharePoint designer workflow? If so, there is not a OOTB feature to achieve it.